# Difference between JRMP vs HTTP

Tags: java, spring, rmi, httpinvoker, jrmp

While going through spring  remoting  i came across remoting vis RMI and via HTTP invoker.
The only striking difference between the two seemed to be the protocols used by the two ie JRMP(java remote method protocol) by rmi and  http by http invoker.
can some one please there knowledge on the difference between these two protocols as i am unable to find it across the web.

Thanks

Jayendra

Comment: The difference is that they are different. So different that they have very little in common beyond a request/response structure. Both have formal specifications which are available online to be read. A complete answer to this question would constitute a recitation of both specifications. Off topic and too broad.

Answer (score -1):

http is a stateless protocol.The main messages exchanged are in XML or JSON format.
You can look up JRMP here is this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Remote_Method_Protocol